# gradle war deployment - replace some files

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gradle, war

I have the following project structure

```
...
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/menu/menu.jsp    
...
src/prod/webapp/WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp
```

If i now use the gradle war plugin i got

```
build.war/WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp (from the main directory)
```

In Maven i had

```
<profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/prod/webapp</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

So when i used the prod-Profile the login.jsp from the prod-Directory was used. In gradle i tried

```
webAppDirName=src/prod/webapp
```

This works finde. Now the login.jsp from the prod-Directory was used. But the menu.jsp is missing. The maven plugin replaces existing files from the main directory with files from the profile. The gradle WAR-Plugin just use the files from the wepAppDirName. What is the best way to do it right in gradle.

Want i want in the war file

```
build.war/WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp (from the prod directory) 
build.war/WEB-INF/views/menu/menu.jsp (from the main directory)
```

In real life if have a lot of directories in the main directory and a lot of directories in the prod direcotry.